# Azure copy data failed to read data from http server

Tags: azure, http, copy

I am new to ADF.  I created an http linked service and it tested successfully (https://rebrickable.com/downloads/).  On the http dataset properties page the same url address is in the **Base URL**. I then put just the file name that exists on that page (themes.csv.gz) in the **Relative URL**.  When I click next to the **File format settings** page the Preview pane says:

> Failed to read data from http server. Check the error from http
> server：The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. The
> remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. . Activity ID:
> 0ca9f9c7-438d-461a-81c1-f81bacace4ca

What am I doing wrong please?

I also tried to create a new linked service and point it to my desktop files. I selected'File', left it at AutoresolveIntegrationruntime, put the path in Host.  But don't know what do to with User/password.  Please help

Answer (score 0):

I hit the above  mentioned end point in by browser : https://rebrickable.com/downloads/themes.csv.gz

[image]

Looks like the file is not existent at the mentioned location.

I did a quick scan of the page https://rebrickable.com/downloads

Encountered the below file :

[image]

Saw the file hyperlinked to this url (This is different from what you're attempting to in the ADF)

https://cdn.rebrickable.com/media/downloads/themes.csv.gz

I was able to download the file by using the above.

Would suggest you to try the above endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

Update your url to https://cdn.rebrickable.com/media/downloads/ in https connection source

Comment: What is the additional insight this contributes on top of what is already desribed in the existing answer by Satya V?